# Schema validation Array issue

Tags: java, karate

I cannot validate schemas that contain arrays, especially if the number of objects is different per request.

Example response:

```
{
  "name": "value",
  "id": "value",
  "arrayField": [],
  "objects": [
    {
      "Field1": "value",
      "Field2": false,
    },
    {
      "Field1": "value",
      "Field2": true,
    }
  ]
}
```

Bare in mind, that another request may have more objects in the objects array. Also, I do need to check that the Field1 and Field2 are present.

In the feature file, I use the classic:

```
 def expectedSchema = read('path to json')
    match response == expectedSchema
```

Problem is, I have tried multiple solutions in the schema, but I always get the error:
$ | not equal | actual does not contain key - '#array' (MAP:MAP)
or something similar.

Schema version 1 which will fail if the number of objects is different:

```
{
  "name": "#string",
  "id": "#string",
  "arrayField": "#array",
  "objects": [
    {
      "Field1": "#string",
      "Field2": "#boolean"
    },
    {
      "Field1": "#string",
      "Field2": "#boolean"
    }
  ]
}
```

Schema version 2 which will fail given the above error:

```
{
  "name": "#string",
  "id": "#string",
  "arrayField": "#array",
  "objects": "#array"
  "#array": [
    "Field1": "#string",
    "Field2": "#boolean"
  ]
}
```

Is there a way to validate the schema successfully?

Comment: Your JSON is invalid. Run it through [JSON Lint](https://jsonlint.com/) to see the issues.

Comment: Sorry, thats not the actual json i am getting, but i fixed the above.

Answer (score 0):

Already explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61252709/143475

Personally I would just do a `match each`. My advice is teams should not obsess over trying to crunch validations into a schema - and certainly not a "single" schema.

```
* match each response.objects == { Field1: '#string', Field2: '#boolean' }
```

Comment: The problem with that solution is that if the response is large, I will have to fill the feature file with * match. Imagine 10-20 lines. That would make the file even less readable for the user.

Comment: But it seems that it might the best available solution. Right?

Comment: @TimLks if your "schema" is large, yes. the first link gives you the solution I think you want. you will have to declare variables for each sub "chunk". you can use `read()` if you want to re-use the schema "setup" across multiple features: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58334900/143475

Comment: Based on the solution stackoverflow.com/a/58334900/143475, is it possible to have the schemas in files instead of having them declared as def in the feature?
I cannot comment on the post.

Comment: @TimLks yes. just curious - do you think validating "schema" is the most important thing you should be doing in API testing ?

Comment: No, but its very good to have, especially with long happy path scenario responses. I am just trying to cover everything.

Comment: @TimLks so my personal opinion is that you should tackle the "unhappy" paths before worrying about schema (which 99% of the time will work fine because of many reasons): https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/api-contract-testing-visual-guide-peter-thomas/